# Url Signalr/hubs returns 404 for browsers on Android

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, http-status-code-404

When requesting the url example.com/signalr/hubs with any browser on Android, the response has status 404. On all other platforms (Windows, iPad, iPhone) the url returns a javascript file.

We can replicate this even with F12/developer tools in Chrome browser on my machine, where when we set the browser to e.g. Nexus 5X the file /signalr/hubs returns 404 and when we change the browser to iPad it file is successfully loaded.

Everything is working in development but not in production. We have tried to check http handler mappings, cors etc on the production environment, but to no avail. Additionally I don't see why these would be dependent on user agent.

Comment: Check IIS log files to see what sub status you get. 404 is a big family.

Comment: Did you check if the browser is supported - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms? Someone in the comments also had problems with android devices.

Comment: The SingnalR server was installed in Sharepoint and turned out that the problem was in the Sharepoint installation and not in SignalR or it's code.